# Error en tablas mysql mariadb

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Resulta que tengo un problema con mysql el cual me ha sucedido varias veces y nunca lo he podido solucionar, cuando sucede un evento ya sea apagón o alguna mal funcionamiento el servicio de MySQL se detiene y me muestra lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y las tablas salen con una lupita la cual no deja ver la información, me encantaría saber como recuperar esa tabla he intentado de todo y no he podido ojala alguien pueda darme una luz gracias...

Comment: me imagino que le asignaste todos los privilegios al usuario ?

Comment: lo que sucede es que estaba funcionando bien hace mucho tiempo y de repente el error, si esta con los privilegios

Answer (score 0):

Puedes verificar si se estan omitiendo las definiciones de permisos al inicio de mysql. Es mas facil identificarlo si simplemente reinicias el servidor normalmente y ves si se reproduce el mismo error.

Revisar por ejemplo si en `my.cnf` contiene las opcion `skip-grant-tables` (que puede omitir las asignaciones de permisos) o en el comando de inicio del servicio tiene las opciones `--init-file` (que peude tener comandos que eliminen permisos) o `--skip-grant-tables`.

Si solamente pasa cuando se apaga el servidor repentinamente (sin un cierre normal del servicio), debes revisar los logs del servidor Mysql (generalmente en la raiz de la carpeta de datos) en busca de procesos erroneos o mensajes de error.